# UIFont and Color give an Expected expression error

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, uifont

I'm getting an Expected expression error the the 1st and last line though I'm fairly certain the code is correct. Any clue?

```
_lblStatus.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:16.0];
_lblStatus.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_lblStatus.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0 alpha:1.0f];
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There's nothing in the console, the build fails and the line is highlighted in red saying "expected expression

Comment: Just  "expected expression – ? Maybe you can try to clean the project and rebuild it. For the last line, I see it is `)` in the end instead of `]`. I'm not sure whether it is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem lies with my computer, i tried the code elsewhere and it worked fine